# How to append a file into a File Input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to create a `file drag and drop` feature.

I've the drag and drop working from the div and handling the file.

Now I now would like to append this file to the `Input[type=file]` of the form .

How could I do that?

I tried `uploadFormData.append("files[]",f);` and derivates but it doesnt work. My debugging was submit the form and check the headers to see if the file was sent.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how achieve this?

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="yourregularuploadformId">
         <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
    </form>

<script>
      var uploadFormData = new FormData(jQuery("#yourregularuploadformId")[0]);

        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();

        var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.

        var output = [];


        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                      f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                      '</li>');
               uploadFormData.append("files[]",f);
        }

        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
      }
</script>
```

Comment: You want to silently add a file to an input file without any user interraction, is it what you want?

Comment: I want to add the file from a drag and drop div

Comment: Ok, so user drag a file in a div and you want to add this file in a input file[] ?  If yes, why not let your user directly drag file to an input file?

Comment: Maybe if you find a way to hide the input file but i seriously see some security holes here and im quite sure it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do it this way because you can't dynamically fill an `<input type="file" ....>`  just because if this was allowed, that mean you can grab any file from the user's computer without any validation.

What you can try to do is bind an event like `.change()` on your div to trigger when a file is dragged, then make an ajax call on that bind that will upload the file, and finally get the file name (or whatever you want when the upload is finished) from the ajax callback and process it the way you want

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to convert file to Base64 (using `FileReader`) and upload as a string

```
  var input = document.getElementById('image');

  function readImage(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
     input.value = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

Example: https://codepen.io/ndan/pen/KJqZVd

FileReader docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/FileReader

ps.

- Don't store images in Base64 in your DB
- The best solution is to use direct file upload to the cloud storage (s3, gcloud, etc)